# Django manytomany field failing with "relation does not exist" due to model being in separate app. Change order of app creation?

Tags: django

I have a model in an app (we'll call it Report) that is referencing a manytomany on another model in a separate app (Notes).  When I run manage.py syncdb I keep getting the error relation does not exist because the database table for the Notes model hasn't been created yet.  Is there a way to control the order in which syncdb will create database table to fix this problem?  My first guess was the ordering of the apps in installed_apps but Notes is definitely before the Report in installed_apps.

Comment: Post your models. You should relate with strings. For example, to make an FK to the User model, use: ForeignKey('auth.user')

Answer (score 2):

Check for, and resolve, any circular imports. This is when one models.py imports from another which also imports from the original. For example, App Report imports models from Notes, but Notes also imports from Report. The only way to change the order of creation, is to change the order of the INSTALLED_APPS and the order in which they are in the models.py files. As jpic said, you can reference the M2M reference object with quotes and the app name dot model name, like:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    whatevers = ManyToManyField('Notes.whatever_model')
    .
    .
    .
```